# How to play a mediaplayer in the background while controlling it with a service/activty?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, media-player

I am a developing an app which runs mp3 files, I want the app to run the mp3 files after the activity is closed, In which case I used a service but I want to connect the activity with the media player to display seekbar progress and stop and play the media player from the activity, I tried to use broadcasting between the service and activity but it seems to cost a lot of resources, Is there a better way to to this?

Here is a part of how I done that

```
public class Reciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int command = intent.getExtras().getInt("command");
    if (command == 0) {
        progressDialog.setMessage("loading...");
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    if (command == 1) {
        int value = intent.getExtras().getInt("value");
        seekBar.setMax(value);
        int seconds = (value / 1000) % 60;
        int minutes = ((value / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
        int hours = ((value / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
        if (hours != 0) {
            if (seconds < 10) {
                durationTV.setText(hours + ":" + minutes + ":0" + seconds);
            } else {
                durationTV.setText(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
            }

        } else {
            if (seconds < 10) {
                durationTV.setText(minutes + ":0" + seconds);
            } else {
                durationTV.setText(minutes + ":" + seconds);
            }
        }

        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    if (command == 2) {
        int currentDuration = intent.getExtras().getInt("value");
        if(!movingSeekBar) seekBar.setProgress(currentDuration);


        int seconds = (currentDuration / 1000) % 60;
        int minutes = ((currentDuration / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
        int hours = ((currentDuration / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

        if (hours != 0) {
            if (seconds < 10) {
                currentPositionTV.setText(hours + ":" + minutes + ":0" + seconds);
            } else {
                currentPositionTV.setText(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
            }

        } else {
            if (seconds < 10) {
                currentPositionTV.setText(minutes + ":0" + seconds);
            } else {
                currentPositionTV.setText(minutes + ":" + seconds);
            }
        }

    }

    if (command == 3) {
        bufferPercent = intent.getExtras().getInt("value");

        seekBar.setSecondaryProgress(bufferPercent);

        Log.d("Media Player", "" + bufferPercent);
    }
}
```

}

I don't think that the receiver was efficient plus I had another receiver on my service as well, How to play the music in the background while controlling the media player from the activity/service

Comment: sure: "bound local service" pattern

Comment: After some reading the pattern is exactly what I need submit an answer maybe with a link to google's docs and I will accept it, Thank you very very very very much, I spent 3 days trying to go around this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use "bound service" then, most likely it is going to be a "bound local service", more info on this pattern can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder)